# Influence of artificial sunlight on the human body

Tags: skin, human-physiology, health, light, uv

In a hypothetical scenario, where a large, permanently manned craft is in a continual orbit, and natural sunlight cannot be used as the craft may keep moving and turning, artificial sunlight is used in the form of LED panels.

My question is this: Will the LEDs have any adverse effect on the human body? The LEDs are of the [SoLED variety](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/SOLED-stacked-organic-light-emitting-device) which have very low IR levels and almost nil UV light levels, have any adverse effects on the body? I suppose the lack of UV may cause some disturbance in Vitamin D and melanin levels. Is this valid? Would there be any other problems?

Comment: You could easily supplement Vitamin D.

Comment: But will that be the only issue?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Natural sunlight doesn't have a good substituent.

Melatonin levels and circardian rhythms are directly affected by natural sunlight.

As far as LEDs goes, a french study concluded that blue light may have photochemical risks and affect our retina.

Source

http://www.ledinside.com/knowledge/2014/4/effect_of_artificual_and_natural_light_on_the_human_body